# Need to replace NoneType with empty string while converting Excel sheet to JSON file, Any idea how to implement this?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to convert an .xlsx file to JSON using a python script, however there are null spaces in the sheet and I need to convert it to empty strings. How can I implement this ? My current code is :

Edit : By null space I mean the corresponding entries in the excel sheet are empty

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

import json

wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Python39\data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

my_list = []

last_column = len(list(ws.columns))
last_row = len(list(ws.rows))

for row in range(1, last_row + 1):
    my_dict = {}
    for column in range(1, last_column + 1):
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
        if row > 1:
            my_dict[ws[column_letter + str(1)].value] = ws[column_letter + str(row)].value
    my_list.append(my_dict)

data = json.dumps(my_list, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
with open('C:\\Python39\data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Could you print out exactly what are this "NoneType"/"null spaces" ?

Comment: What I meant is that the corresponding entries in the excel sheet are empty, and they have to be replaced by an empty string. This is the error I get : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: If you use the openpyxl API properly, your code would be a lot easier to read. As it is, it looks to me like the dictionaries will be overwritten all the time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you passed `sort_keys=True` to `json.dumps`, but your dict contains some keys which are `None`.  JSON objects can only contains string keys (I think the error message here is not so helpful--I think `json.dumps` should explicitly check first if all the keys are strings and raise a more helpful error in this case).  For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'a': 1, None: 2}
>>> json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

You just need a condition in your code like:

```
key = ws[f'{column_letter}1'].value
key = '' if key is None else key
my_dict[key] = ws[f'{column_letter}{row}'].value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, followed this approach.

Comment: @DevdattN If it helped, please kindly upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this and replace NULL_PATTERN by whatever string of charachters you want:

```
NULL_PATTERN = ''
for row in range(1, last_row + 1):
    my_dict = {}
    for column in range(1, last_column + 1):
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
        if row > 1:
            key = ws[column_letter + str(1)].value
            value = ws[column_letter + str(row)].value
            my_dict[key if key else NULL_PATTERN] = value if value else NULL_PATTERN 
    my_list.append(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook(r'C:\\Python39\data.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb.active
myList = []
for r in range(2, len(list(ws.rows)) + 1):
    myDict = {}
    for c in range(1, len(list(ws.columns)) + 1):
        cl = xl.utils.get_column_letter(c)
        if (k := ws[f'{cl}1'].value):
            if not (v := ws[f'{cl}{r}'].value):
                v = ''
            myDict[k] = v
    myList.append(myDict)
print(myList)
```